# How to perform sql query with date range

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, date-range

I have this SQL Server tables:

[image]

I need to group together each category of streams and show the user an overview of the last weeks, as evidenced in this image:

[image]

This datatable interrogates a web service that, in turn, queries the database.

**The color of checkmarks depends on the value CodState**: if there is also one state equal 4 ('Denied') then the checkmark is red. Otherwise, is green.

Please note that the Date field DetailsStream corresponds to a certain day.

**The problem is the formulation of the query with different ranges of dates** (in the picture: the latest five weeks, from Monday to Friday).

**EDIT**

As suggested, my **tables schemas**:

```
-- Category:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StreamCategory](
    [Cod] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_StreamCategory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Cod] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]



-- Stream
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stream](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [TypeStream] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [CodCategory] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Stream] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Stream]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Stream_StreamCategory] FOREIGN KEY([CodCategoria])
REFERENCES [dbo].[StreamCategory] ([Cod])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Stream] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Stream_StreamCategory]
GO



-- State Details stream
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StateDetailsStream](
    [Cod] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DetailsStream] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Cod] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]



--  Details stream
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DetailsStream](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [DateStream] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CodStateDetailsStream] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IdStream] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DetailsStream] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DetailsStream]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DetailsStream_StateDetailsStream] FOREIGN KEY([CodStateDetailsStream])
REFERENCES [dbo].[StateDetailsStream] ([Cod])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DetailsStream] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DetailsStream_StateDetailsStream]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DetailsStream]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DetailsStream_Stream] FOREIGN KEY([IdStream])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Stream] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DetailsStream] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DetailsStream_Stream]
GO
```

**Inserts**:

```
-- StreamCategory

INSERT INTO [myDb].[dbo].[StreamCategory]
           ([Cod]
           ,[Name])
     VALUES
       (1,'Category A'),
       (2,'Category B'),
       (3,'Category C')
GO



-- Stream

INSERT INTO [myDb].[dbo].[Stream]
           ( [CodCategory]
            ,[Name]
           )
     VALUES
        -- Category A:
        (   1       ,'Stream001'    ), -- IdStream: 1
        (   1       ,'Stream002'    ), -- IdStream: 2
        (   1       ,'Stream003'    ), -- IdStream: 3
        (   1       ,'Stream004'    ),
        -- Category B:
        (   2       ,'Stream005'    ), -- IdStream: 5
        (   2       ,'Stream006'    ),
        (   2       ,'Stream007'    ),
        (   2       ,'Stream008'    ),
        -- Category C:
        (   3       ,'Stream009'    ), -- IdStream: 9
        (   3       ,'Stream010'    ), -- IdStream: 10
        (   3       ,'Stream011'    ),
        (   3       ,'Stream012'    )
GO



-- StateDetailsStream

INSERT INTO [myDB].[dbo].[StateDetailsStream]
           ([Cod]
           ,[Description])
     VALUES
       (1, 'InProgress'),
       (2, 'Received'),
       (3, 'Ko'),
       (4, 'Declined')
GO



-- DetailsStream

DECLARE
@mon    as datetime = '20/06/2016'
DECLARE
@tue    as datetime = @mon+1,
@wed    as datetime = @mon+2,
@thu    as datetime = @mon+3,
@fry    as datetime = @mon+4


INSERT INTO [myDB].[dbo].[DetailsStream]
           ([IdStream] -- fk
           ,[DateStream]
           ,[CodStateDetailsStream]
           )
    VALUES
        -- Category A
        (1  ,@mon           ,2  ), -- Stream001
        (1  ,@mon           ,2  ),
        (1  ,@tue           ,2  ),
        (1  ,@tue           ,2  ),
        (1  ,@wed           ,3  ),
        (1  ,@wed           ,2  ),
        (1  ,@thu           ,2  ),
        (1  ,@thu           ,2  ),
        (1  ,@fry           ,2  ),
        (1  ,@fry           ,1  ),
        (1  ,@mon+7         ,1  ),
        (1  ,@mon+7         ,1  ),
        (1  ,@tue+7         ,3  ),
        (1  ,@tue+7         ,4  ),
        (1  ,@wed+7         ,2  ),
        (1  ,@wed+7         ,1  ),
        (1  ,@thu+7         ,2  ),
        (1  ,@thu+7         ,2  ),
        (1  ,@fry+7         ,4  ),
        (1  ,@fry+7         ,2  ),
        (2  ,@mon           ,2  ), -- Stream002
        (2  ,@mon           ,4  ),
        (2  ,@tue           ,4  ),
        (2  ,@tue           ,2  ),
        (2  ,@wed           ,3  ),
        (2  ,@wed           ,2  ),
        (2  ,@thu           ,2  ),
        (2  ,@thu           ,2  ),
        (2  ,@fry           ,2  ),
        (2  ,@fry           ,1  ),

        -- Category B
        (5  ,@mon           ,2  ), -- Stream005
        (5  ,@tue           ,2  ),
        (5  ,@wed           ,2  ),
        (5  ,@thu           ,2  ),
        (5  ,@fry           ,2  ),

        -- Category C
        (10 ,@mon           ,1  ), -- Stream010
        (10 ,@mon           ,2  ),
        (10 ,@tue           ,2  ),
        (10 ,@tue           ,3  ),
        (10 ,@fry           ,2  ),
        (10 ,@fry           ,4  ),

        (11 ,@wed           ,4  ), -- Stream011
        (11 ,@wed           ,1  ),
        (11 ,@thu           ,2  ),
        (11 ,@thu           ,3  )
```

(NB: I don't know if it might be interested, but usually I use this methodology: Web Form code-behind -> WebService -> Core -> Repository, with entities and DTOs  to communicate between the different levels)

Comment: Love the graphs! Can you post the SQL you have written so far to meet your requirement, so that we can help you with whatever specific problem you are having? Thanks.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using a Calendar table (which is useful for a number of date related calculations...

Here is a reference for one: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Using this table you can join on the date key to your relevant date, then group by the other fields in the Calendar table; by the sounds of it the Year and Week. This should allow you to easily report in weekly periods